# I believe this asian artwork is from China. I am seeking the translation of this artist signature! I will include photo of signature!

Tags: translation

Could someone help me translate this artist signature please?  Many thanks in advance!  Picture attached.  [image]

Comment: potentially 筆 for the last

Comment: the last character looks like some combination of 筆 and 下

Comment: googling 常信筆 brings up Japanese art

Answer (score 4):

I managed to find another piece by the same artist.

Tsunenobu hitsu “常信筆”– Japan 17th – 18th century

https://www.catawiki.com/l/23453837-painting-silk-flowers-cotton-rose-large-painting-on-silk-signed-tsunenobu-hitsu-japan-17th-18th-century-japan-edo-period-1600-1868

[image]
[image]

Comment: Oh thank you SO very much!